# Error stating my object has no '_on' method when jquery-ui autocomplete is applied

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been stuck on this one for a while now, I'm getting the error:

```
Object # < Object > has no method '_on'
```

In .NET MVC 4 I have all the necessary jquery ui includes for autocomplete (autocomplete, core, menu, position, and widget), jquery-ui-1.8.20.js, and jquery-1.7.1.js. I know that .on() was released in jquery 1.7.

Here is the complete stack trace for the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_on' jquery.ui.autocomplete.js:78
$.widget._create jquery.ui.autocomplete.js:78
$.Widget._createWidget jquery-ui-1.8.20.js:473
$.widget.$.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) jquery-ui-1.8.20.js:370
$.widget.bridge.$.fn.(anonymous function) jquery-ui-1.8.20.js:436
jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.7.1.js:658
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery-1.7.1.js:271
$.widget.bridge.$.fn.(anonymous function) jquery-ui-1.8.20.js:431
(anonymous function) add:110
jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery-1.7.1.js:1046
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery-1.7.1.js:1164
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.7.1.js:435
DOMContentLoaded jquery-1.7.1.js:923
```

I'm sure the object exists because doing a console.log(object) shows the object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the order you are including the javascript libraries in? make sure jQuery is included first and all the other jquery-requiring-libraries after

Comment: You're looking at the wrong .on - it's complaining about _on which is a method added in jQuery UI's $.Widget.prototype.  You're not accidentally mixing different jQuery UI versions are you?

Comment: @dherman, that was exactly my problem. I must have been using the jquery ui that came with the MVC 4 project, but I got the latest jquery ui autocomplete files. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

Include a more recent version of **jquery.ui.widget.js** which includes the `_on` method.

[Download JqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/)

[See jquery.ui.widget.js On Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js)